# NVRM: No NVIDIA graphics adapter found!

Tags: nvidia, login

Once in a while when I install updates on my laptop and system requests a reboot, I get into a login loop.  I've discovered that this is not because I have driver issues, but rather that my discrete Nvidia GPU isn't detected during reboot - in other words, `lspci -nnk` in a terminal session will not list the Nvidia card.  If I attempt to then login to the GUI, I'm returned to the login screen.  If I reboot until the output of `lspci -nnk` shows that the Nvidia card is available, I'm then able to login to the GUI.

In the logs, I see the message `NVRM: No NVIDIA graphics adapter found!` and I'm wondering if anyone else has encountered this issue and found a solution.

The laptop in question is a Dell Precision m6700 bought back in 2013 and still has a lot of life left in it.  I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS.

Comment: You may have to open the laptop and reseat the Nvidia card.

Comment: Which Nvidia driver version have you installed, and how?

Comment: @heynnema - I'll do as you suggest - it never crossed my mind to do that on a laptop though I've always preached that to desktop users.

Comment: @MichaelBay - I have Nvidia driver v375.66 installed via Additional Drivers.